# Error when mounting a NAS drive on Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: server, mount, nas, cifs

I've got a problem that I just can't figure out. Tried looking at other answers and working through the suggestions, but I still get the same error.

I have a ReadyNAS drive with CIFS enabled and shares set up. I can access the shares from Windows and from Ubuntu Desktop 8. There are no username/passwords needed to access the shares.

However, I am now setting up an Ubuntu server using 11.10 and when I try to mount the share using the following:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //nasdrive/media /mnt/ReadyNAS/media
```

I get the following error:

```
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I've tried adding "-o uid=1000,gid=1000,username=guest,password=" as well, with the same results. I am a bit of a newbie with command line Linux, so please be gentle with the jargon.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: Well, after a couple more hours of poking around, I found a post over at the readynas.com forums that said they basically create "hidden" accounts for each share.  Changed my mount command to include -o user=media,password=,nogroup and, et viola, I'm all set. Furrfu.

Comment: You should write your comment as an answer, because it answers your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A post at the readynas.com forums led me to the answer to my own question (eventually!). Basically, ReadyNAS creates a user, starting at UID=1000 and with nogroup, for each share that you create. It never really tells you its doing this, but it does.

You can see/edit these using their FrontView web application, under Security > Account.  For me, I simply used the following entry in FSTAB

```
//ReadyNAS/media /mnt/ReadyNAS/media -o user=media,password=,uid=1000,nogroup,ro,noserverino,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

Note that the ReadyNAS CIFS implementation does not support server-side inode numbers, so to avoid a bunch of warning messages, be sure to include the noserverino option.

Also, this is a read-only mount to access a media library, so I didn't use password protection. If I was using a password, I would substitute a credentials file and use the credentials= option instead of user/password.

Hope this helps!